# Validate list of codes in Javascript with an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have list of codes almost 1000 codes like "PB5KE13" and i have to check these codes through input field. If the input value have a code then show Ok message. Is there anything I can get through Javascript. I don't want these in PHP or Database. I can't use these. Only HTML and Javascript.
I know the if else condition. but with this large list may be i can't use.

```
<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
    <input type="text" name="inputfield" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="validate">
  </form>
<script>

  function checkForm(form)
  {
    // validation fails if the input is blank
    if(form.inputfield.value == "") {
      alert("Error: Input is empty!");
      form.inputfield.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Put all 1000 elements to an array and listen for the input change event then use array function find to match your input value.

Answer (score 0):

If there is are codes to be validated, it is recommended to validate with server side script like PHP as Javascript is client side and anyone can see your code and it would not make much sense to ask for a code. But in case I misunderstood your requirement, Here is Javascript code:

```
let inputField = document.getElementById('#code');
let codes = ['PB5KE10','PB5KE11','PB5KE12','PB5KE13','PB5KE14']; // Can add More

function validate(val,code){
    result = false;
    for(let i=0;i<code.length;i++){
        if(val==code[i]){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(validate(input.value,codes)); //true if value is in array else false
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all the codes in an array in Javascript, the only thing you need to do is use the includes() method on an array:

```
myKeys.includes(myInputValue);
```

Check out the W3Schools link for details:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp

Hope it helps!